# Android tooltip activity

Tags: android, tooltip

I am trying to prepare my activity's "how to use" windows but I am facing some concept issues actully way of approach.

I see some applications those works like;

while the app is starting; A transparent window shows the newly added features or a button's duties. For example the latest youtube app update contains the subscribed channells usage tip at the very first starting of the youtube app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate your tooltip activity after the creation of the main activity, with transparency settings. For this purpose you can read this other response:

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: so basically I can manage the background image just like the activity window which just contains the tipping point is not blurred and some cool fonted text message could help me. Thanks ! I will give it a try !

Answer (score 1):

You can make your activity themae like..

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

and put a variable in shared preferences to check first launch of the app.